# efficient parsing of large nested json into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I would like to parse this json `Affiliations` into a text file of entries without the email addresses:

```
# example of one entry: total entries: ~1million
{
  "_index": "group",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "9890798789",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "Bibtex": {
      "Article": {
        "AuthorList": [
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "Some departmentA, some university, city, country. Electronic address: gh@example.com."
            }
          },
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "Some departmentB, some university, city, country. Electronic address: jh@example.com."
            }
          },
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "Some departmentA, some university, city, country; Institute, Sydney, country. Electronic address: yu@example.com."
            }
          },
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "Some department some university, city, country. Electronic address: nj@example.com."
            }
          },
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "department, university, Sydney, country. Electronic address: bg@a.b.au."
            }
          },
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "Some departmentA, some university, city, country. Electronic address: we@example.com."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output: text file with the following for one entry:

```
Some departmentA, some university, city, country; Institute, Sydney, country.
Some departmentB, some university, city, country.
Some department some university, city, country.
department, university, Sydney, country.
....
more entries from other nested jsons
```

I have some 1million entries of varying lengths, so I am unsure how to parallelise (say GNU parallel or python mp) and still have unique entries with no email addresses.

Comment: read the whole string, split it from point where email start split that and save it or `string[:-string[::-1].find(' ')]` and save this is text file

Comment: you can read the json using the built in json library and then convert the dict to a pandas DataFrame. Look into the explode method. I might post an answer later when I have more time

Comment: How are these million objects stored? In an array? JSON lines? What?

Comment: @Shawn they are json lines in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having sample input that includes multiple records would be handy for testing, but here's one way using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), the de facto standard tool for working with JSON data in shell scripts (Any shell, not just bash):

```bash
$  jq -r '._source.Bibtex.Article.AuthorList[] | .Affiliation.Affiliation | .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")]' input.json
Some departmentA, some university, city, country.
Some departmentB, some university, city, country.
Some departmentA, some university, city, country; Institute, Sydney, country.
Some department some university, city, country.
department, university, Sydney, country.
Some departmentA, some university, city, country.
```

Iterates over the array of affiliations, gets just the string you're interested in from those objects, and extracts just the parts up to the substring " Electronic address:" from them. The results are printed as raw strings, not JSON-encoded strings thanks to the `-r` option.

Comment: thank you Shawn for showing me `jq`. Yes it seems to work! I have one questions however: (1) Although it does not get the `Electronic address:` it does seem to get the email address for some reason. Do you not get this? How do I avoid it extracting the email (without any regex I hope!).

Comment: Also, for some jsons which are empty I get `jq: error (Cannot iterate over null (null)` how can i do a try catch on it and `pass` this?

Comment: @JohnJ Works for me with your example object. If the real data includes other formats, you should include them in your question too.